# How to create a single image of Windows Server 2008 R2 to use on a Azure Virtual machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-storage

I am trying to migrate from a colocation where I own the servers to Azure.

I have been following this article: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-create-upload-vhd-windows-server/

My problem is that I cannot create a bootable .vhd file, I used Windows Server Backup and that created multiple .vhd files and when I use HyperV and set each of .vhd to the Virtual Hard Disk of the HyperV Virtual Machine, to boot up any of the multiple .vhds, and none are bootable.

I want to make an image or .vhd of my server, so I can upload to Azure storage blob and then create a new virtual machine with it.

I heard Disk2vhd was the solution I needed:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-create-upload-vhd-windows-server/

So this is a a physical machine. I tried creating a vhd with Disk2vhd. The process was successful been when I try to start a VM, using HyperV, and setting the Virtual Machine IDE to the vhd created with Disk2vhd I get a cannot boot disk error. I ran chkdsk against the vhd and there are no errors, I am able to attach to the vhd and browse files using the Disk Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Sysprep is important for migrating bootable images to azure. So follow the sysprep steps in the link that you posted.

After shut down, try running through this:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/how-do-i-create-a-virtual-image-of-a-working-windows-installation-with-disk2vhd/

If that doesn't work, is the machine physical or virtual? If it's physical are there multiple disks?

If it's virtual, what platform is it running on? These would probably be easier and be more reliable.

If it's VMware:
http://www.2tware.com/product/6/2tware+convert+vhd+free

If it's Hyper-V:
There are ways pre-built to do this. I can't post another link (because of lack of reputation), but just google: "Move VM’s between Hyper-V and Windows Azure"

Hope this helps and good luck!

=Devon

Comment: So this is a a physical machine. I tried creating a vhd with Disk2vhd. The process was successful been when I try to start a VM, using HyperV, and setting the Virtual Machine IDE to the vhd created with Disk2vhd I get a cannot boot disk error. I ran chkdsk against the vhd and there are no errors, I am able to attach to the vhd and browse files using the Disk Manager.

Comment: Just to verify, you ran sysprep, shut down the machine and ran disk2vhd from a thumb drive?

Comment: So I ran sysprep on the machine I want to get an image of and shut the machine down. You are saying that I now need to boot the machine backup and run disk2vhd from a thumbdrive connected to the machine?

Comment: upon further research, you shouldn't need to. Are you running a hyper-v or vmware cluster? They have "p2v" tools that I have always used. What version of windows is the server you are trying to image?

Comment: Its Windows Server 2008 R2. Its a physical machine, not a virtual machine, so I am not running hyper-v or vmware cluster.

 I see that disk2vhd will run right on the machine and save the .vhd on the same physical drive it is copying.

So I ran sysprep on the machine, now all I need to do is boot the machine back up and run disk2vhd on the machine?

Comment: According to microsoft, you shouldn't even need to do that. Make sure you uncheck "use vhdx" and have "use volume shadow copy" checked.

Comment: Hey so my machine will not boot up after running Sysprep, getting a getting windows server installation prompt, any clues?

Comment: That's the point of doing "sysprep". It will ask you to install everything again. Disk2VHD doesn't require it. It does it itself. There are options during install to keep everything, so don't worry about that.

Comment: If you're worried about losing info, you can do a clonezilla backup via usb drive. But, just go through install prompts of windows and use disk2vhd without sysprep. Microsoft built sysprep into disk2vhd, don't know why they said those things in that article.

Comment: So the Windows server is asking for the installation disk which I do not have...any thoughts?

Comment: The server is prompting for the installation disk on bootup after running sysprep I should say